# ldap_mod_add() Modify: Server is unwilling to perform in

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap

Want to use ldap_mod_add command with SSL on Centos but get the following error message;

```
PHP Warning: ldap_mod_add (): Modify: Server is unwilling to perform in ...
```

However the SSL ldapsearch command is working well;

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://winsvr.intra -b dc=windows, dc=intra -D "DOMAIN\user"-w "123456"
```

The required **Windows.pem** file is in **/etc/ssl/certs/windows.pem** directory and has the appropriate line in **/etc/openldap/ldap.conf**.

Indeed getting above error message.

What else should I configure to work properly?

**Updated:**

Everything's OK. Problem was that I didn't recognize existing AD user. That's why the ldap_mod_add returned with above error messages (it couldn't add same AD user through ldap_mod_add).

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP client in your PHP example is apparently doing an update, whereas the `ldapsearch` tool is doing a search, not to point too fine a point on it. The configuration of the server, the nature of the target entries involved, and any access controls involved might affect the update but not the search.